# How to animate correctly a GSAP menu?

Tags: javascript, gsap

Holla, I need to reset the animation when I close menu and open it again. How can I do that? Animation works only the first time when I open menu.

```
CSSPlugin.defaultTransformPerspective = 600;
TweenMax.staggerFrom('ul#menu li', 1.5, {rotationX:-90, transformOrigin:"50% 0%", ease:Elastic.easeOut}, 0.4);
```

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/hafsadanguir/pen/qOdaab.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **[this](http://codepen.io/tah_med/full/yYNamy/)** the kind of result you were after?

***JavaScript:***

```
CSSPlugin.defaultTransformPerspective = 600;
var toggleMenu = $('.menu-toggle');
var logo = $('#logo');
var logotitle = $('#logotitle');
var listItems = $('ul#menu li');
var timeline = new TimelineMax({ paused: true, reversed: true });
timeline.fromTo([logo, logotitle], 0.6, { top: 300 }, { top: -50, ease: Power2.easeInOut });
timeline.staggerFromTo(listItems, 1.2, { autoAlpha: 0, rotationX: -90, transformOrigin: '50% 0%' }, { autoAlpha: 1, rotationX: 0, ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.3) }, 0.1, 0.3);

toggleMenu.on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('on');
  timeline.reversed() ? timeline.play() : timeline.reverse();
});
```

A few things have changed so here are the details:

- First and foremost, I didn't see the need for the `hidden` class so I have removed it from my solution.
- Plus, the `on` class *toggled* on the `.menu-section` element seemed pretty unnecessary as well. I removed it, but kept the properties defined on the `.menu-section` CSS rule.
- On to the fun part, the JavaScript.
- You basically needed a **[`TimelineMax`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/)** to operate upon.
- Judging by the imports you had in the JavaScript settings panel, I am assuming that you have some idea of what `TimelineMax` (and `TimelineLite`) are all about. By in any case, `TimelineLite` is about *building and managing sequences of TweenLite, TweenMax, TimelineLite, and/or TimelineMax instances* and `TimelineMax` is an extension of `TimelineLite`, adding more power to it.
- So, what happens in the code is that a `TimelineMax` instance has been initialised, tweens have been added to it and then, upon clicking of the `.menu-toggle` button element, this timeline is either *played* or *reversed*.
- The line `timeline.reversed() ? timeline.play() : timeline.reverse();` is basically a shortened, fancy version of an `if` condition and it comes to down to personal preference more than anything else, no performance gain or anything that I am aware of. In a normal `if` clause, it would have been written like this:

  - `if (timeline.reversed()) { timeline.play(); } else { timeline.reverse(); }`.
  - The condition that is being checked is **[`.reversed()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/reversed/)** property of `timeline`. You would notice that while initialising `new TimelineMax(...)`, I set `reversed: true` property on it. What it does is that after all the tweens are added to `timeline`, it would behave as if `timeline` was immediately reversed such that the orientation of the `timeline` had been flipped. Read more about it in the `TimelineMax` documentation link I shared above.
  - The **[`.play()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/play)** and **[`.reverse()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/reverse)** methods are pretty self-explanatory as they make the `timeline` go *forwards* or *backwards* respectively.
- That is about it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thansk a lot for you're quick reply Ahmed ! that's exactly the effect I was looking for stil have one more question what this line means plz timeline.reversed() ? timeline.play() : timeline.reverse();

Comment: Sure. this is basically a shortened version of an `if` condition. Let me add the details about it in my answer.

Comment: Added. Let me know if you have any other questions. Don't forget to choose this as the right answer if it did help :)

Comment: Thaks for the explanation !! actually for the hidden line code I have two element I want to hide when I open Menu a base line and scroll down mouse

Comment: I see. I guess you have a use of `hidden` I wasn't aware of. Apologise for that. Add it back again.

Comment: No worries  :)   if (logo.style.top == '-50px') {
          TweenLite.to([logo,logotitle], 0.5, {top:"300"});
          $("h2, .scroll-prompt, .scroll-prompt2, .mouse").show();
    }

Comment: Hmm I have a feeling this can also be optimised or included in the `timeline`. Do you want to have a go at it yourself first? :) Give it a try. I could be wrong though.

Comment: aside from what we are doing right now, quick ques: you didn't fork from my pen right? because I cleaned up the dependencies you had in JS scripts you imported. I see them back all over again :)

Comment: @Hafsa: I modified. Take a **[look](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/ZbGXvL?editors=001)**.

Comment: basically, whenever you need to add something in the `timeline` you add them like everything else, i.e. outside of the `click` scope. secondly, there is an `autoAlpha` special property provided by GSAP which does two things: set `opacity` to `0` and set `visibility` to `hidden` when you set `autoAlpha` to `false`. So I have used this special property. Lastly, I cleaned up the dependencies again. `TweenMax` includes `CSSPlugin`, `TimelineMax` & `TweenLite` within it so no need to import them all over again. Plus, I used the latest of the `TweenMax` version.

Comment: Also, `bootstrap` requires `jQuery` to be loaded beforehand (if you look in the console of your browser, `bootstrap` throws an error that it needs `jQuery` loaded before using `bootstrap`). So I re-arranged that as well.

Comment: Anyway, back to the code. I have resorted to use `fromTo` with some duration instead of `staggerFromTo` with a duration of `0` that you were trying to do. I also have given it a position of `0` so that it starts animating as soon as the `timeline` kicks in. Does that help?

Comment: Hello Tahir Ahmed I need u're help please ! i'ts about the menu again ! @Tahir Ahmed

Comment: when I scroll to bottom  want the logo to stick on top of the window                    function sticky_relocate() {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var div_top = $('#logo').offset().top;
        console.log(window_top,div_top);

        if (window_top < div_top) {
             timeline.fromTo([logo], 0.6, { top: 200 }, { top: -40, ease: Power2.easeInOut }, 0);
              timeline.reversed() ? timeline.play() : timeline.reverse();
        } 
    });
}

Comment: do you have a pen that I can look into?

Comment: what do you mean scroll to bottom? do you mean that when you touch the bottom border whilst scrolling or do you mean that even if you just slightly start scrolling down, the logo should stick to top and when you reach top again, the logo should get to its position?

Comment: If I just slightly start scrolling down, the logo should stick to top and when I reach top again, the logo should get to its position !

Comment: hmm! let me see what I can do.

Comment: I have no answer from you !

Comment: sorry about that. but I am a bit busy for now. Will look into it over the weekend.