# JS: Iterate over array, display each item sequentially in a notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm attempting to iterate over an array, displaying each item sequentially in a notification that:

1. slides up from bottom with a CSS animation
2. delay while displayed for 3 seconds
3. slides back to bottom with css animation
4. interval of 8 seconds before next item is loaded

Also, the notification should remain on screen while mouse over, and hide (after second delay) on mouse out.

I have the following issues:

1. How do I create a delay of 3 seconds after a css animation?
2. How do I iterate over the items sequentially? In the code below they are executed at once.
3. How do I pause and resume the animations?

https://jsfiddle.net/3905wogc/1/

```
    $(function() {
        var delay = 3000,
        interval = 8000,
        $el = $('#notification'),
        data = [{
            id: 1,
            content: 'First Notification'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            content: 'Second Notification'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            content: 'Third Notification'
        }];

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {

            console.log (item);

            // add the content to the html
            $el.html(item.content);

            $el.addClass('in');

            $el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {

                // animate in complete
                console.log('in complete', i);

                // add delay before slide out
                $el.removeClass('in').addClass('out');

                $el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {

                    // animate out complete
                    console.log('out complete', i);

                    // add interval before next slide in
                });
            });
        });

        $el.on('mouseover', function () {
            // pause the animation 
        });

        $el.on('mouseout', function () {
            // resume the animation 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hey i am working on your code

Comment: Rewrite your code so each "step" (_`nextItem`, `show`, `hide`_) is it's own function, as you would for asynchronous or event driven code, then you can use `window.setTimeout` at the end of each to chain them together, recursing if there are more items, and finally invoke the first in the chain to set it going

Comment: Usually we try to focus on a single problem per post.

Comment: @AsaCarter: https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/rdzo13cf/

Comment: @TahirAhmed: That syntax looks so simple. Does tweenMax also work in non CSS transform supported browsers?

Comment: I believe so. check these previous answers out: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441947/how-to-animate-correctly-a-gsap-menu/32442836#32442836) and [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209926/jquery-animations-sequence/32211160#32211160) to get you started with **GSAP**. These links further carry plethora of links to GSAP stuff.

Comment: @TahirAmed: Using your example code, I am triyng to exit the timeline at the end of the cycle instead of looping. However, it never displays the last item.

Comment: @TahirAhmed: Posted as new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997633/stop-iteration-when-end-of-data-objects-are-reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is it [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3905wogc/3/)

```
var delay = 3000,
    interval = 8000 + delay,
    $el = $('#notification'),
    data = [{
        id: 1,
        content: 'First Notification'
    },
            {
                id: 2,
                content: 'Second Notification'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                content: 'Third Notification'
            }],
    currentItem = 0 ,
    timeoutTrack ,
    intervalTrack;

showNextOne();
var intervalTrack = setInterval(function(){showNextOne();},interval);


function showNextOne()
{
    $el.html(data[currentItem].content).addClass("in");
    timeoutTrack = setTimeout(function()
    {
        $el.removeClass("in").addClass("out");
        setTimeout(function(){$el.removeClass("out");},1500);
    },delay);
    if(currentItem +1 >= data.length)
        currentItem = 0;
    else
        currentItem++;
}

$el.on("mouseenter",function()
{
    if(timeoutTrack)
        clearTimeout(timeoutTrack);
    if(intervalTrack)
        clearInterval(intervalTrack);
});
$el.on("mouseleave",function()
{
    timeoutTrack = setTimeout(function()
    {
        $el.removeClass("in").addClass("out");
        setTimeout(function(){$el.removeClass("out");},1500);
    },delay);
    intervalTrack = setInterval(function(){showNextOne();},interval);
});
```

Comment: It'd be nice to summarize what the problem was

Comment: there was no problem , his code was missing some lines

Comment: There is a small issue when hovering over the notification while it is sliding back down.

Comment: @diptox a few missing lines is not a problem? I still suggest you explain in words what was wrong

Comment: @JuanMendes I was not sure of the logic to time CSS animations, delay, pause and resume them and how to put it all together.