# Stop iteration when end of data objects are reached

Tags: javascript, gsap

Using the **TweenMax** library, I am unable to kill or stop a `delayedCall` when the end of the data object is reached instead of looping because it is a self calling function.

https://jsfiddle.net/rdzo13cf/6/

In the example above the last item in the data is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's because you are incrementing your `iter` variable before you set it. Which causes it to not display the last item, you want to increment after:

```
function setContent() {
    element.html(data[iter].content);
    iter = iter >= data.length-1 ? -1 : iter;
    iter = iter + 1;    
}
```

Basically you are going over indexes `[1,2,3]` when you want to be going over `[0,1,2]`.

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdzo13cf/8/)

Comment: if I do that `data[iter]` is undefined after the last item.

Comment: @AsaCarter Ah your right, because of the change in the offset you want to do `data.length-1 ? -1 : iter ` rather than `data.length ? -1 : iter `.